# Button click navigate to another view

Tags: extjs, extjs-mvc, extjs4.1

I have a button and when ever the user clicks it, i need to show a different view/page (navigate to a different view).

For example, Screen A, has a button, and when i click on that button, i need to navigate to Screen B.

my code is as follows;

```
onLoginSuccess : function(){
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {

                    items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'screenb'
                    }
                    ]
                });
}
```

but, what hapence is that, When i click on the Button in Screen A, i navigate to Screen B and also Screen A appears on Screen B. I need to get rid of Screen A (after the user clicks the button and show only screen B)

===================== **UPDATE 2** =======================================

```
Ext.define('Proj.view.loca.Person' ,{
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel', 
    alias : 'widget.person',

    items: [

            {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Name',
        name: 'name'
    }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'School',
        name: 'school'
      }],
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Submit',
        handler: function() {
            var form = this.up('form').getForm();
            if (form.isValid()) {
                form.submit({
                    success: function(form, action) {
                    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {

                    items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'screenb'
                    }
                    ]
                });

                    },
                    failure: function(form, action) {
                    // Navigate to some other view
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve this is using a card layout.

Here is roughly how it's done:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'BS',

    appFolder: 'app',

    refs:
    [{
        ref: 'viewport',
        selector: 'viewport'
    }],

    launch: function() {

        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'card',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                id: 'panel1',
            },{
                xtype: 'panel',
                id: 'panel2',        
            }]
        });
    },


    onLoginSuccess : function() {
        this.getViewport().getLayout().setActiveItem(1);        
    }

});
```

Comment: Isn't there any other way i could do it, because i will have to change my entire code to make the above changes :S

Comment: There might be, but you'll have to provide more of your app/controller/view code for us to help.

Comment: Well, you'll have to change some code I believe - you are rendering a viewport from the button handler of a panel. I'm not sure how come the form panel is displayed (was there another viewport in the app launch?), but if it's rendered it is in the document body already when you add the viewport to it. Regardless, I would argue that it is a good and standard practice to create the viewport upon app launch. I doubt anyone has ever created the viewport like you did.

Comment: I have a viewport in the app launch. I am new to Extjs, can you tell what should i do to navigate from one view to another ?

Comment: That's why you have the problem - you create 2 viewports. I honestly think my original answer is the right way to go about it - create two panels within your viewport, and just do `getLayout.setActiveItem(1)` when you want to navigate to the other panel.

Comment: but i don't understand what `onLoginSuccess : function() {` is. who calls this method ?

Comment: The handler of your submit button, like in the code you have provided. You should have `this.application` in scope, so just call `this.application.onLoginSuccess()`

Comment: My handler button is in another View, called `Person`. And what you have given here is the app.JS file. So can i access the handler button from App.JS ?

Comment: Your controller has `this.application` referring to your application object.

Comment: Is there an example/sample code, that shows this. I am a bit confused :S

Comment: I added the code `onLoginSuccess()` as shown in your example to my App.JS , both `panel1` and `panel2` gets displayed when the app is launched.

Comment: And the layout set to `card`?

Comment: I have to add it. After adding, the `onLoginSuccess()` which is in the app.js is not called. Therefore the 2nd panel is not displayed. It is going to the `success: function(form, action) {
...` block but not to the `onLoginSuccess()` on the app.js

Comment: The `onLoginSuccess()` should be called from your button handler. Does it?

Comment: Call this.application.onLoginSuccess() from the `success` function of your `form.submit`; Just make sure the scope is that of the controller.

Comment: It says `this.getViewport is not a function`.

Comment: And you have the `refs` defined in your app? What does `console.log(this)` shows if you put it as the first line of onLoginSuccess()?

Comment: yes i have added them in the `app.js` file. When i `console.log(this)` i get `Object { name="Proj", appFolder="app", controllers={...}, more...}` . There's whole lot of info in it.

Comment: That's odd. you console log shows the application object, so your scope is fine. Could be a typo. Anyway, try putting `this.vp = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {.....` ,and then replcae `this.getViewport()` with `this.vp`.